# .sh executable asking for definition for INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME path to jvm

Tags: java, jvm

I want to run a .sh executable to install software but when I try to execute the file using `./<fileName>` in my terminal, following error message appears:

`No suitable Java Virtual Machine could be found on your system. The version of the JVM must be 1.8. Please define INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME to point to a suitable JVM.`

1. How does one check the JVM version on the device?
2. If the JVM isn't version 1.8, how can one install JVM 1.8?
3. How does one define INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME to point to the JVM?

Answer (score 0):

1. `java --version`
2. `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre`
3. `export INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME=pathToJVM`

`update-java-alternatives --list` to manage installed java versions

Comment: Step 3 (export INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME=pathToJVM) will not be necessary after installing Java 1.8, because the .sh executable will find the installation.